# Accessing images in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

I used following code to access an image from "res" folder with NetBeans

```
imgWelcome = Image.createImage("/cover.png");
img = new ImageItem(null, imgWelcome, ImageItem.LAYOUT_CENTER, "");
```

Though the resource is not getting detected and i keep on getting NullPointerException. As weird as it sounds, exactly same technique worked in my previous program.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. I've double checked that the file exists in the res folder

Comment: Does the image appear in the res folder in your ide? If not -> f5 the folder in ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow.. this was because .png was not supported by my emulator. And what all I tried :(

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons for this, but I have found that most of the time, it is due to how the project is built. Some build scripts include the resources in the `res/` folder as top-level files, and some include that folder as a folder in the jar file.

What I have always done to troubleshoot is to rename the jar output to zip and look inside. If the image files are contained in a folder then you should address them as such.

Comment: In my case, the jar contains the image not inside any folder. What do I do?

Comment: Himmm... I guess you should then try to access it as: `Image.createImage("cover.png")`.

Comment: That is not working either. btw my code is in a different package than the default one. Does that make any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't as long as they are all being compiled into the same jar file. Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code **will not find `cover.png` if it is in the `/res` folder**.

Inspect the contents of your jar using 7-Zip or similar, ensure the image really is in the `/res` folder, then replace the first line with `imgWelcome = Image.createImage("/res/cover.png");`.